# count number of times Y happen in fact(X,Y) in Prolog Programming

Tags: prolog

I am new in prolog programming and I trying to experiment with it
I have 2 questions

1. suppose I have some facts

   fact('A', 'B').
   fact('A', 'C').
   fact('A', 'D').

when I write fact('A', X), the X will be of 3 values 'B', 'C', and 'D'
how do I write a rule to get how many times 'A' has a pair, in this case the answer will be 3

2. suppose I have a fact

   a([1,2,4,5]).

how do I write a rule to loop through the elements to add them, i.e. find the sigma

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can collect a list of solutions and get the list's size:

```
?- findall(X, fact('A',X), List), length(List,Count).
List = ['B', 'C', 'D'],
Count = 3.
```

or better use the aggregation predicates from [`library(aggregate)`](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=aggregate):

```
?- aggregate(count, X^fact('A',X), Count).
Count = 3.
```

Note caret-notation `X^` to signify that  `X` is not a variable over which `aggregate(count, Goal_with_X, Count).` should backtrack (giving three times a count of 1) but a free variable of the `Goal_with_X` which varies over the bag of solutions whose size shall be assessed.

Comment: hi thanks, it works for me. do you perhaps know how to do the second one as well (find the sigma)? Thank you

Comment: @NickyPratama To sum over the list, there is actually a [`sum_list/2`](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=sum_list/2) predicate, so you can just do: `a(L), sum_list(L,Sum).`

Comment: @NickyPratama Note that there is an edge case for `aggregate/3`: If fails instead of giving `Count == 0` in case there are no solutions. Use `(aggregate(count, X^fact(c,X), Count) -> true ; Count=0).` to make sure you get a `Count` of 0 instead of failure.

Comment: You could use `aggregate_all` instead, it is more obvious and doesn't suffer from the edge case in your comment. Try: `?- aggregate_all(count, between(1,3,_), N).` (no need for "existentially qualified variables") and `?- aggregate_all(count, fail, N).` Somewhat related to the difference between bagof/setof and findall both in semantics and implementation. See also the docs.

Comment: why does doing 'sum_list(a, Sum)'  return false, why do i have to put a(L) in front?

Comment: @NickyPratama You have your list of numbers in a fact: `a([1,2,4,5]).`. So first you have to grab that list from the fact and put it into a variable, so you do: `a(L).`. Now `L` is `[1,2,4,5]`. So now you can perform ` sum_list(L,Sum).`. But of course the `L` is only the same `L` in the context of a single goal to execute (otherwise it's all different `L`s), so your run both instructions together into a single goal: `a(L), sum_list(L,Sum).`

Comment: @NickyPratama The full story is, you almost never save facts like this: `a([1,2,4,5]).`, this is usually written as a table instead. See my answer.

Answer (score 4):

If you just need to count solutions and you are using SWI-Prolog, use `aggregate_all`:

```
?- aggregate_all(count, fact('A', _), N).
```

This way you don't need to existentially qualify variables, you can just "skip" it from the query by using an anonymous variable in its place.

This also correctly counts 0 solutions without further code tricks:

```
?- aggregate_all(count, fail, N).
```

To sum a list, you can use `sum_list/2` from library(lists). Note that you could also use library(aggregate) for this, if you have a backtrackable predicate (a table of facts) instead of a list. This is also the more usual way to represent a "list" of things in the database.

```
a(1).
a(2).
a(4).
a(5).
```

This is how you'd usually find the sum of all rows in your table:

```
?- aggregate_all(sum(X), a(X), Sum).
Sum = 12.
```

You can have more columns in your table, of course.

```
p(a, 3).
p(b, 2).
p(b, 1).
p(a, 2).
p(a, 0).
```

You can sum those like this:

```
?- aggregate_all(sum(X), p(a, X), Sum).
Sum = 5.

?- aggregate_all(sum(X), p(b, X), Sum).
Sum = 3.

?- aggregate_all(sum(X), p(foo, X), Sum).
Sum = 0.

?- aggregate_all(sum(X), p(_, X), Sum). % total sum
Sum = 8.
```

In contrast, you can use `aggreagate` to get the different groups:

```
?- aggregate(sum(X), p(A, X), Sum).
A = a,
Sum = 5 ;
A = b,
Sum = 3.
```

Comment: Actually, I would really disrecommend writing the `a/1` as a series of individual facts like that. I recommend: `a(X) :- memberchk(X,[1,2,3,4,5])`.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer It really depends what you are doing with it. Either way, for most use cases, normalized data is better. You can of course keep a list inside a column if you really want to.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer You got me curious. Why would you not recommend this? Can you give me a good reason to _not_ keep the list elements as column values in separate rows? (I can come up with good reasons but they are rather contrived use-cases.)

Comment: No need to overthink. It's just syntax - a simple 1-arg fact like is friendly to maintain using a list (although one must use `member/2` not `memberchk/2` as I stupidly wrote). OOH, indexing will be missing and you get additional nondeterminism as in `a(X) :- member(X,[a,b,c,c,d]).` when asking `a(c)`.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer I had to overthink it to figure out how a list there is useful :-) but it maybe only because I have some limited experience with relational databases, this have definitely biased me a bit.

Comment: I think this is mainly something that comes from the Java-addled side of my brain.